# Applying CLAHE on RGB images

Tags: python, image-processing

I applied CLAHE to improve the image visibility (original image). However, it looks like after applying the CLAHE, the visibility of imagery is not improved in the shadow areas (CLAHE image). Please suggest me how to improve quality of my imagery. Below are my script:

```
# Input and output folder paths
input_folder = r'D:\imagery_shadow\clip_3b'
output_folder = r'D:\CLAHE\clahe'

# List all image files in the input folder
image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(input_folder) if f.startswith('shadow_image') and f.endswith('.tif')]

# Iterate over each image file
for image_file in image_files:
    # Construct full paths for input and output images
    original_image_path = os.path.join(input_folder, image_file)
    process_image_path = os.path.join(output_folder, image_file.replace('.tif', '_clahe_V3.tif'))
    
    # Convert the image to LAB Color
    img_cv = cv2.imread(original_image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    lab_img = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)

    # Split the LAB image into L, A, and B channels
    lab_planes = cv2.split(lab_img) 

    # Apply CLAHE to L channel
    clahe = cv2.createCLAHE(clipLimit=2, tileGridSize=(3, 3))
    clahe_images = [clahe.apply(plane) for plane in lab_planes]
    

    # Combine the CLAHE enhanced L-channel with A and B channels
    updated_lab_img2 = cv2.merge(clahe_images)

    # Convert LAB image back to RGB color space
    processed_rgb_img = cv2.cvtColor(updated_lab_img2, cv2.COLOR_LAB2RGB)
    cv2.imwrite(process_image_path,processed_rgb_img)
```

[image: Image 1] (original image)

[image: Image 2] (clahe image)

Comment: what are you trying to see in the shadows of that tiny image?

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz: I would like to see whether in the shadow areas is there any small trees? In addition, I would like to better visible better boundaries between a tree crown and shadow for individual trees segmentation and calculate the tree crown size.

Comment: since all of that happens within a handful of pixels... you don't have enough resolution for that. I also don't think CLAHE will remove shadows.